# wp_insert_post with data from graph api inside a plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-insert-post

I'm creating a plugin that creates a post in a CPT for every Facebook page post (using fb graph api). When should I fire the function that gets the data? using an action? Also if I understood the docs correctly, the `wp_insert_post` takes ID as an argument, which if doesn't exist, sets the newly created post id to that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to get notifications from Facebook for a new post. You have to check **by hand**. Just set a transient with the desired expire time for the data so you don't make a request on each reload, maybe check hourly for new data or every 30 mins, up to you.

As for your second question, read the docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

It automatically assigns an ID unless provided by you (which is auto-incremented by the system) but you still need to provide more things in the array, even if some are default, you might not want it like that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Good idea to set an expire time, coz for now I just set it to plugins_loaded action. About the ID, I miss-understood, just setting a value to ID doesnt set the ID (if not already set), apparently I can use 'import_id' instead.. still working on it coz it hasn't worked till now.

Comment: @SilvesterVella I mean, that's just how transients work. I'd honestly say not to touch the ID. Unless you have a very good reason for having a custom one (which, if you do, let me tell you, you're probably wrong), it messes up the internal auto-increment in the database, say you have a post with ID 352, but you suddenly decide to insert a post with ID 300, which doesn't yet exist, so it's valid, what will happen is that now your auto-increment is reset to 300 in the database, **if I remember correctly.**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that info. To be honest, the idea was so that it won't create duplicate posts, so I figured if the ID exists (which was going to the date/time of the facebook post created) it will update that post, if not, create a new. Given what you said, better if I just check the post title or slug or someting.

Comment: @SilvesterVella Duplicates can never, ever happen in WordPress in terms of ID, but if you reset the auto-increment, your post "logic" might not make sense at some point, as in "why the hell does this have this ID but it was posted before this post with a higher ID?"

Comment: True. When I said duplicate posts, I meant because the plugin will create posts for every facebook post. So every time it gets the json data, it will create posts with the exact content. But if I just check the date or something before, shouldn't be a problem. I was complicating things for a minute there.